# Getting a List of Children from a Dynamic Media Node

Tags: razor, umbraco

So I am trying to create a photo Gallery by getting all the images in a folder from the media section. Using Umbraco 4.7.0 I used to be able to do this in Razor.

```
DynamicMediaList images = new DynamicMediaList(new DynamicMedia(galleryImage).Children.Items);
```

I Upgraded to 4.7.1.1 and now I get the error 'umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicMedia' does not contain a definition for 'Children' and no extension method 'Children' accepting a first argument of type 'umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicMedia' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Did some googling and found ChildrenAsList, but I can't seem to get it to cast I get the message Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

```
List<DynamicMedia> images = new DynamicMedia(galleryImage).ChildrenAsList;
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not the System.Collections.Generic.List object.  It's the generic type inside.  I would try

```
var images = new DynamicMedia(galleryImage).ChildrenAsList;
```

This is the preffered way of instantiating objects with .NET 3.5 and 4, as the use of the dynamic and var datatypes free developers from the concerns of unbalanced equations like this.

Only time when I use anything other than var on the left, is when it's hard to see the end type, and I know what it will be.

Incidentally, you will probably get List assigned to the images field.

Hope this helps.